# Filter web parts no longer available in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-parts

My company switched from an onsite SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint Online.

I had some pages that consisted of multiple web parts, including the [filter web parts](https://www.codesharepoint.com/sharepoint-tutorial/filter-web-parts-in-sharepoint-online).

I've rebuilt these pages in Sharepoint Online, but none of the filter web parts are available.
Every list is set to use classic experience - except the site itself, which I do not have control over.

According to IT support these specific filter web parts are simply not available in SharePoint Online, and therefore they can't help me.

I honestly don't trust that answer completely, which is why I'm asking here ;-)

So:

1. Can the filter web parts be made available for classic view in Sharepoint Online?
2. Suggestion on what would need to be configured in order for these to be made available?
3. Possible links to official Microsoft documentation?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my test, the filter web parts are available in SharePoint Online. As the below picture shows:

[image]

You could donot have access to the web part gallery. Ask the site admin to give your access to the web part gallery: please go to site settings-> Web parts, grant the user access to the library.

Comment: Thank you. I can actually access 'settings > web parts', and get a list of currently installed web parts. However the filter web parts do not seem to be there.
From your POV, would that suggest that they've been purposely removed, or just never installed?